# How do I use Unicode in a button (rails form_for)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, erb

```
<%= f.button "Vote &#9650;" %>
```

I'm trying to print text + a Unicode triangle. Can't find the syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, strings output in Rails views are automatically escaped.

You will need to stop it from escaping it by telling Rails that the string is HTML safe:

```
 "Vote &#9650;".html_safe
```